# What are other ways to say "cutting off 2.5% from the tails"?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, interpretation, simulation

I was reading a text that state

> Cutting off $2.5\%$ from the tails of these simulated distributions gives us Bayesian interval estimates of $\mu$ and $\theta$.

I was wondering what are other ways to say the same?

An equivalent way?

Comment: Finding quantiles 0.025 and 0.975. // If you do this for the posterior distribution of $\mu$ then you have the 95% Bayesian posterior probability interval (also called 95% cerdible interval.

Comment: Quote in yellow box speaks of interval estimation. Need more context if you want to test hypotheses. No foundation here for answering that. // Please try to edit you question so it is clear what you're asking. // To start, do you have a particular posterior distribution in mind?

Comment: @BruceET thanks. It is actually not for hypotheses test it is for simulation of bivariate Markov Chain with 2 vectors mu and theta.

Comment: @BruceET the posteriors that are being considered are $\mu|\theta,x\sim(\mu',\sqrt\theta')$ and $\theta|\mu,x\sim IG(\alpha',\kappa')$ where each parameter has an specific 'definition'. Then there is the `r` code, specially this line I think has to do with the quote "cutting off.." `bi.MU=quantile(MU[aft.brn],c(.025,.975))`. How do I interpret this line of code?

Comment: @BruceET Never mind. I have figured  out. sorry for disturbing.

Comment: Looks as if the posterior is estimated by a Gibbs sampler., and you _did_ figure it out. Glad for that.